# Java box then widen on == operator

Tags: java

```
Number n = 10; 
int i = 10;
System.out.println(n == i);
```

Based on "You CAN box then widen". Why the above code gives a compile time error?
My guess is that if *i* will be first boxed to Integer and widened to Number the result will always be false.
There are any specification referring to *==* operator when comparing a primitive with an object? Will always try to perform unboxing and the if necessarily will widen?

Comment: What compile-time error?

Comment: Works fine. Proof: http://ideone.com/pvxPOt

Comment: @jlordo. Surprisingly, doesn't work on my Machine.

Comment: Maybe it depends on the Java version. Can you post which version you use and whether it compiles for you?

Comment: Compiles on 1.7_0_21-b11 64 bit.

Comment: According to the spec, it *shouldn't* work. If it does, I'd like to see the assembly output.

Comment: @AaronDigulla i used jdk 1.7

Comment: @L4zy: Which IDE? Eclipse uses its own compiler.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Per the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2), `==` comparisons between a boxed and an unboxed value result in an *unboxing* conversion, not the other way around (or else you'd be using reference equality, not value equality). The compiler can't unbox a plain `Number`; `Number` itself isn't "convertible to [a numeric type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2)."

The Java 7 compiler appears to be being clever. The assembly output for this version and for the version in which the comparison is moved into a `private` method completely ignore the declared type `Number`, and everything works properly. Make that method `public`, and the behavior is as specified: The conversion isn't one of the listed types for which unboxing will occur, and the compiler boxes `10` to an `Integer` and compares by reference, meaning that if you try using `Integer.valueOf(10)`, you'll get `true` for the range -128..127, and if you use anything else (another width, `new Integer(10)`), you'll get `false`.

Output from your code (note that `Number` appears nowhere, and that you're getting comparison based on reference equality in line 18; try using `L` or casting to `short`):

```
public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
  Code:
   0: bipush        10
   2: invokestatic  #2                  // Method java/lang/Integer.valueOf:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
   5: astore_1      
   6: bipush        10
   8: istore_2      
   9: getstatic     #3                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
  12: aload_1       
  13: bipush        10
  15: invokestatic  #2                  // Method java/lang/Integer.valueOf:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
  18: if_acmpne     25
  21: iconst_1      
  22: goto          26
  25: iconst_0      
  26: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Z)V
  29: return
```

Version that prevents optimization:

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Number n = new Integer(10);
        compare(n);
    }

    public static void compare(Number n)
    {
        int i=10;
        System.out.println(n == 10);
    }
}
```

Assembly; note that you're still getting a reference comparison in line 12:

```
public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
  Code:
   0: new           #2                  // class java/lang/Integer
   3: dup           
   4: bipush        10
   6: invokespecial #3                  // Method java/lang/Integer."<init>":(I)V
   9: astore_1      
  10: aload_1       
  11: invokestatic  #4                  // Method compare:(Ljava/lang/Number;)V
  14: return        

public static void compare(java.lang.Number);
  Code:
   0: bipush        10
   2: istore_1      
   3: getstatic     #5                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
   6: aload_0       
   7: bipush        10
   9: invokestatic  #6                  // Method java/lang/Integer.valueOf:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
  12: if_acmpne     19
  15: iconst_1      
  16: goto          20
  19: iconst_0      
  20: invokevirtual #7                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Z)V
  23: return
```

Comment: [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8) are the acceptable unboxing conversions.

Comment: @chrylis can you point me exactly where it is stated that unboxing is prefered in place of boxing?

Comment: @arshajii Thanks for the correction; I grabbed the wrong anchor. Fixed.

Comment: @chrylis: I removed my downvote but I don't see a difference in the second version. When I make the method private, it doesn't change anything :-/

Comment: -1: You are linking to the wrong section of the JLS specification. "Section 5.6.2 - Binary Numeric Promotion" does not explain the behaviour. The Java compiler is also not supposed to be clever, but to follow the JLS. Nevertheless, the code in the question is *not* a comparison between a boxed and an unboxed value, so it is irrelevant what the JLS writes on that subject. The code attempts to use the == operator with one parameter being of a numerical type and the second being a "non-unboxable" reference type. This is not supposed to work.

Comment: @AaronDigulla The compiler appears to be out of compliance with the spec in a DWIM fashion. Note that the spec specifically requires an *unboxing* conversion here, but the compiler is *boxing* the `int` in such a way that it's probably what the programmer meant. The Eclipse compiler is correct.

Comment: @jarnbjo I can't find any other section of the JLS that talks about the `==` operator and autoboxing, and my point is that this behavior appears to be contrary to the literal specification.

Comment: @chrylis: If you didn't manage to find the JLS specification of the equality operator (==), how could you claim that "Per the JLS, == comparisons between a boxed and an unboxed value result in an unboxing conversion"? The relevant section is 15.21.

Comment: @jarnbjo 15.21.1 simply refers to 5.6.2 and then has a one-liner summary of it.

Comment: @chrylis: 15.21.1 defines the numerical equality operator, which is not applicable in this case since java.lang.Number does not fulfill the type requirements in the first paragraph.

Comment: @jarnbjo Correct. But the Oracle compiler is, contrary to the spec, autoboxing the `int` literal to an `Integer`. The Eclipse compiler is correctly throwing a compile-time error.

Comment: So you're saying this is a javac bug?

Comment: @arshajii Essentially, yes, in the "do-what-I-probably-meant" direction, but still dangerous and Wrong. I posted the actual compiler output, and it quite clearly does not agree with the spec.

Comment: @chrysis: You are right in your last comment, that the int shouldn't be autoboxed to an Integer. Up to that, your argumentation is more or less wrong. You starts with discussing what to do when comparing what you call "unboxed" and "boxed" types, and that's not what the question is about at all. In the question, the code is trying to compare a primitive numeric type with a reference type, which can not be unboxed. The spec especially do *not* require an unboxing conversion here, as you wrote in one of your other comments.

Answer (score 3):

The code in your question gives me "Incompatible operand types Number and int" with Java 6 and 7 using the Eclipse compiler. With `javac` from Oracle's Java 7 SDK, it compiles and prints `true`.

Why?

The assignment `Number n = 10` will be converted into `Number n = Integer.valueOf(10);`

Later, the compiler will create `n == Integer.valueOf(10)` (autoboxing the int value).

This gives true because `Integer.valueOf()` keeps an internal cache for small integer numbers and always returns the same instance for them:

```
Integer.valueOf(10) == Integer.valueOf(10)
```

But this is a just a side effect of the implementation, you should *not* rely on it.

Bytecode:

```
  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: bipush        10
       2: invokestatic  #2                  // Method java/lang/Integer.valueOf:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
       5: astore_1      
       6: bipush        10
       8: istore_2      
       9: getstatic     #3                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
      12: aload_1       
      13: iload_2       
      14: invokestatic  #2                  // Method java/lang/Integer.valueOf:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
      17: if_acmpne     24
      20: iconst_1      
      21: goto          25
      24: iconst_0      
      25: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Z)V
      28: return
```

Answer (score 1):

The compiler in Oracle's JDK 7 allows you to compile the code by auto-boxing the primitive, but this violates the Java Language Specification.

According to [JLS section 15.21](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21), there are 3 variants of the equality operator:

15.21.1. Numerical Equality Operators == and !=

Describes the equality operator "if the operands of an equality operator are both of numeric type, or one is of numeric type and the other is convertible (§5.1.8) to numeric type". In this case, one of the operands has a numeric type, but the other operand is not convertible to a numeric type (unboxing).

15.21.2. Boolean Equality Operators == and !=

Describes the equality operator "if the operands of an equality operator are both of type boolean, or if one operand is of type boolean and the other is of type Boolean". This is also not the case.

15.21.3. Reference Equality Operators == and !=

Describes the equality operator "if the operands of an equality operator are both of either reference type or the null type". This is also not the case.

Since the operands to the == operator does not match any of the three variants defined in the JLS, the code should not compile.

What the Java 7 compiler actually does, is to use the reference equality operator by auto-boxing the primtive operand and then compare the references. Since the use of auto-boxing (convertion to a reference type according to §5.1.7) is not documented for this variant, like unboxing (§5.1.8) is specified for the numerical equality operator, the compiler applies functionality not documented by the JLS.

There is a [bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6526449) for this behaviour in JDK 5 and 6, which is allegedly fixed. In Java 7, some automatic conversion and boxing/unboxing cases [were added to the JLS](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6526446) and I almost assume that someone intended to add auto-boxing for the equality operator and left the bug in the compiler without actually updating the JLS.